# what is function (err, results) { in the below?

Tags: node.js, lambda

I am starting with nodejs and read basics on callback, here i have a code,

```
 exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var bx = require('barcode-js');

    // Set default values.  
    var params = {
        input: './1.bmp',
        type: 'qrcode'
    };

    bx.analyze(params, function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
       callback('There was an error processing this image: ' + err)
    }
    results.forEach(function(result) {
        callback(null,'Result type :' + result.type + '\t'+'Value: '+result.value);
     });
});
};
```

what is happening `bx.analyze(params, function (err, results) {`  in this line. why can't we just use bx.analyze(params) ?

Comment: Do you know how async code works?

Comment: @Shaharyar i know about it

Comment: why can, or why can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter is `function`. Called a `callback`.

When you execute an async function, you can't wait for its returned value:

```
var result = bx.analyze(params); //you can't do this
```

So you tell the function that when it finishes its job, just call the `callback` (the function you passed as second parameter).

```
//so `analyze()` will call your passed function rather than `return` the result
//`err` will contain the error object if anything wrong happened in the analyze() function
//`results` will contain result if everything was fine
bx.analyze(params, function (err, results) {
    if (err)
       callback('There was an error processing this image: ' + err)
});
```

I strongly recommend you to learn how async code works in javascript. You can't learn Nodejs untill then..

---

**Update:**

In your code, the function `handler` is an async function so it takes a `callback` as a parameter *(Just like `analyze()`)*.

When this function done with its job, it calls the `callback`.

Now in your code, it is called 2 times:

1) When an error occured, this function will call the callback and pass the error into it:

```
if (err) {
   callback('There was an error processing this image: ' + err); //its passing "err" returned from analyze()
}
```

2) When everything goes well, it passes result set:

```
callback(null, 'Result type :' + result.type + '\t'+'Value: '+result.value); //the 1st parameter is being passed as "null" because there is no error in it, and second parameter passes the result
```

Comment: in this what      callback('There was an error processing this image: ' + err) does?

Answer (score 0):

This is callback function which make the code asynchronous.

Means you are passing a function as argument to your `bx.analyze(params)` method. This callback method is executed once your `bx.analyze(params)` is finished, so its not blocking the other code, making the code asynchronous.

If you need how this call back is executed , then you have to look for `Event loop`, search it in Google,have lots of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

if we use `bx.analyze(params)` then it is blocking (synchronous) code. event loop stop until `bx.analyze(params)` did not return any value and

there is no error handling.

if we use `bx.analyze(params, function (err, results) { });` then it is asynchronous (non-blocking) code. event loop will not wait for returning value it goes to next statement and when `bx.analyze(params, function (err, results) {`  return the callback event loop process it.

There is error handlation is also done

for deep understanding see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ